# Why is my Screen Still Black in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import random, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *


class Display:
    global CELLSIZE, BLACK
    pygame.init()
    CELLSIZE = 20;
    BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)

    def __init__(self,HEIGHT,WIDTH):
        self.HEIGHT = HEIGHT
        self.WIDTH = WIDTH

    def displayBackground(self):
        DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((self.HEIGHT,self.WIDTH))

        for x in range(0, self.WIDTH, CELLSIZE): 
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (x, 0), (x, self.HEIGHT))


        for y in range(0, self.HEIGHT, CELLSIZE):
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (0, y), (self.WIDTH, y))


test1 = Display(600,400)
test1.displayBackground()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pygame.display.flip()` after you are done with your drawing. Look at the [display module documentation for pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html). First you draw your game objects to the display surface. Then you "flip" it (actually show it on the screen).  Every time you do this, you display one "frame" to the screen. Most modern games run at 60 FPS(frames per second) or more due to level of comfort on the human eye. This means that they iterate through a loop 60 times where they draw things to the display surface and then do `pygame.display.flip` to submit the new surface to the display. You can regulate the number of times your loop executes by using `pygame.clock.tick`. This lets you set a maximum framerate that is platform-independent. Again all of this is described pretty well in the Pygame documentation. Ask me if you need any more help :)